# Flutter reset StatefulWidget state when Widget is recreated

Tags: flutter, widget, statefulwidget

In my Flutter Widget I have a `StreamBuilder` that checks for `snapshot.hasError` and in this specific case it will return my `ErrorRetryWidget()`.

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<MyObject> snapshot) {
...
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return ErrorRetryWidget();
    }
}
```

The `ErrorRetryWidget()` just shows an error message and a retry button. When you press this button, I replace the button text by a progress indicator. Therefore I needed to make this widget stateful, as its state holds a `isRetrying` variable that I set to false in the `initState`, and then to true once pressed.

When pressing the button, the `ErrorRetryWidget` tells the parent through a `VoidCallback` to re-trigger the stream logic. It works well but the issue is that if the error comes back, my `StreamBuilder` will "return" the `ErrorRetryWidget` once again.

The constructor is called a new time, but not `initState`. How can I make it so the state resets every time the widget is re-created? Therefore, `isRetrying` is already (or still) set to true.

The only quick solution I found was to implement this in my error widget:

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    setState(() {
        retrying = false;
    });
  }
```

Not sure it's a good practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass a unique key to let it create a new widget.

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return ErrorRetryWidget(key: UniqueKey());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `didUpdateWidget` just as you said, to reset the state of a stateful widget. It is also useful in animations.

The only comment I would add is to NOT use `setState` as you did because when the framework calls `didUpdateWidget`, it immediately calls `build`. Therefore, you don't have to trigger a call to `build` within `didUpdateWidget`. It ends up calling `build` two times.

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    retrying = false;
  }
```